# add/delete image ID to/from textbox when image clicked

Tags: jquery

I am working on a simple news module. There is a form where user adds multiple image IDs to one textbox then submits it. To improve the usability, I listed all the images they can add (ID numbers displayed next to it) on one side. However, this still is little bit confusing. I want image IDs added/deleted to the textbox when user clicks on the images.

Spare me codes, methods, ideas, examples... I will take anything.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create list of hidden inputs: `<input type="hidden" name="photo[ID_HERE]" value="0" />`.
2. Create list of images: `...<li><img src="..." id="photo-123" /> Photo #123</li>...`
3. Add listener for click event for those images that will change value of input associated with image:

   ```
   $("#images img").click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/\D/g, "");
      $("input[name='photo[" + id + "]']").val(Math.abs($("input[name='photo[" + id + "]']").val() - 1));
   });
   ```

Comment: I have a question. When photo clicked, where will the value of that image will be copied?

Comment: But I have a question as well. I put the js code between "$(document).ready(function(){" ? But it did not work. I did not receive any errors either? Where could be the problem?

Comment: I've fixed the code (there were two missing `]` in jQuery selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested)?

```
var $input = $('#textbox'); // <-- your input field

$('img').click(function() {
    var value = $input.val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (value.match(id)) {
        value = value.replace(id, '');
    }
    else {
        value += ' ' + id;
    }
    $input.val(value);
});
```

Comment: If you check and uncheck the same image a few times you'll result with: `123 32 32 32 32`